# SQL Takes too much

Tags: php, sql-server, wamp

For some reason my script takes too much time, that is why i had to add the `ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);` since 30 seconds being the default got me a fatal error.

I can't understand why this is happening, if i go directly into SSMS i get that query in 0 secs. what can be happening? i am running wamp with php 5.4.16 and the extension php_sqlsrv_54_ts

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED);
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
include "ChromePhp.php";
$sort = isset($_POST['sort']) ? strval($_POST['sort']) : 'Cliente';
$order = isset($_POST['order']) ? strval($_POST['order']) : 'DESC';

include "includes/db_config.php";
$conn = sqlsrv_connect(SV_NAME, $connectionInfo) OR die("Unable to connect to the database");
$sql = 
"SELECT  *  FROM
(Select 
    Id
    ,Cliente
    ,Contrato
    ,Anexo
    ,SO
    ,NombreFlota
    ,(SELECT count(*) FROM LiveTest LEFT JOIN Producto ON Producto.Id=LiveTest.Producto_Id WHERE Producto.Order_Id=Orders.Id) as Hechas
    ,((SELECT count(*) FROM Producto WHERE Order_Id=Orders.Id) - (SELECT count(*) FROM LiveTest LEFT JOIN Producto ON Producto.Id=LiveTest.Producto_Id WHERE Producto.Order_Id=Orders.Id and RMA is  null )) as Pendientes
    ,(SELECT count(*) FROM Producto WHERE Order_Id=Orders.Id ) as Total
FROM
    Orders
WHERE 
    Orders.FechaPick is not null) as A
WHERE Total - Pendientes >0
ORDER BY $sort $order";
ChromePHP::log($sql);     
$params = array();
$options =  array( "Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET );
$result = array();  
$res = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql, $params, $options);   
while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_object($res))            
{
    array_push($result, $row);
}   
ChromePHP::log($result);
echo json_encode($result);
```

?>

Comment: how you are passing these values in ssms `ORDER BY $sort $order`

Comment: i sense this as parameter sniffing issue:read this post for more info :[Slow in the Application, Fast in SSMS?](http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html#whatisdynsql)

Comment: @TheGameiswar i am just omiiting them but if i place them it makes no difference

Comment: that makes a large difference,if an  order by doesnt have good index to support,it will cost much

Comment: for sample purposes try running with various values you are passing from app, it will help you understand

Comment: @TheGameiswar if i run the query with the values from order it still takes 0 secs to run

Answer (score 0):

try to modify your query like this:

Note : you do 'where f0b.Order_Id=f1.Id' then your left ouer join is cancelled because you test a value (that's why i have replaced by inner join), if you want null value too, you must do it : 'where f0b.Order_Id=f1.Id or f0b.Order_Id is null'

```
Select 
     Id
    ,Cliente
    ,Contrato
    ,Anexo
    ,SO
    ,NombreFlota
    ,isnull(f3.NbProdLive, 0)  as Hechas
    ,isnull(f2.NbProd, 0) - isnull(f3.NbProdLiveRMANull, 0) as Pendientes
    ,isnull(f2.NbProd, 0) as Total
FROM
    Orders f1
    outer apply
    (
      select count(*) NbProd from Producto f0
      where f0.Order_Id=f1.Id

    ) f2

    outer apply
    (
      select count(*) NbProdLive, sum(case when RMA is null then 1 else 0 end) NbProdLiveRMANull 
      from LiveTest f0 INNER JOIN Producto f0b ON f0b.Id=f0.Producto_Id  
      where f0b.Order_Id=f1.Id

    ) f3
WHERE f1.FechaPick is not null and (isnull(f2.NbProd, 0) - (isnull(f2.NbProd, 0) - isnull(f3.NbProdLiveRMANull, 0))) >0
ORDER BY $sort $order
```